# Centered content but main content and sidebar have there own colors that expanse the screen

Tags: css

I don't know how to articulate this properly so I've attached an image.

The only way I've been able to implement this is with a background image in the body eg: https://www.pro-hyd.co.za/hydraulic-pumps.php

[image: Layout example.]

**Question**: Is there a way to do this using HTML and CSS, without the need for a background image?

Comment: Marked as duplicate but no link to the duplicate question?

Answer (score -1):

You can easily do this with a [flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Flexbox).

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
}

.main {
  background-color: seagreen;
  width: 60%;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="main">Main Content</div>
  <div class="sidebar">Sidebar</div>
</div>
```